# Trouble with Big-O notation proof by definition

Tags: algorithms, big-o-notation, upper-bound

> Let $a,b>0$. Prove
> $\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)^{a}=O\left(n^{b}\right)$.

I'm supposed to find an algorithm to find the log(n) largest elements in an array and return them sorted and explain why it's bounded by $O(n^{b})$, but the thing is I'm having trouble proving the above and I'm kind of stuck.. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

As $a$ is fixed, then you can omit it from requirements because for $a \gt 0$ inequality $(\log n)^a \leqslant C n^b$ is equivalent $\log n \leqslant C^{\frac{1}{a}}n^{\frac{b}{a}}$. Denoting $0 \lt \frac{b}{a}=\alpha $ we obtain, that it's enough to proof $\log n \in O(n^\alpha)$ for $\alpha \gt 0$.

To simplify, we can consider $\log n$ with base $e$, because  the difference with the other base will be constant factor.

So, last step will be
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\alpha n^\alpha}=0$$

We see, that a more strong result with $o$-little is fair: $\forall \alpha \gt 0$  we have $\log n \in o(n^\alpha) \subset O(n^\alpha)$.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [limit definitions for big-O](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925053/using-limits-to-determine-big-o-big-omega-and-big-theta), and try using [Lhopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)