# Show that $(\log(n))^\alpha = O(n^\beta)$

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics

I am trying to show that $\forall \beta \gt0, \log(n^\alpha) = O(n^\beta)$, however I cannot use the limit definition, as demonstrated in similar questions on the forum.

First I show that $\log(n^\alpha) = O(n)$, using the following method:

$\log(n^\alpha) = \alpha \cdot \log(n) \leq \alpha \cdot n$
Thus for $c=\alpha^\alpha, n_0=0$, we have $(\log(n))^\alpha \leq c \cdot n$ which implies $\log(n^\alpha) = O(n)$

Now I will show $\forall \beta \gt0, \log(n^\alpha) = O(n^\beta)$, we have two cases

$\beta \ge 1$: Since $\forall n \ge1, n\leq n^\beta$, then from the above result, for $c=\alpha^\alpha, n_0 = 1$, we have $\log(n^\alpha) \le c \cdot n^\beta$ which implies $\log(n^\alpha) = O(n^\beta)$

$0 \lt \beta \lt 1$: I can't seem to find a series of inequalities, as shown above, that prove $\log(n^\alpha) =O(n^\beta)$ in this case

Comment: Try using the limit definition of big-O instead, and applying Lhopital's rule

Comment: @nirshahar we are not allowed to use the limit definition in our course

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use limits? If $f(n)=O(g(n))$ in limit definition then $f(n)=O(g(n))$ also in the definition with $n_0$ and $c$.

Comment: I don't know why, but my professor insists we only use the "standard" definition. I can use the limit definition to get some intuition about a function that is an upper bound, but I must prove it using the standard definition.

Comment: You can always establish that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\log n)^\alpha}{n^\beta} = 0$ and then formally show that this implies the existence of a $n_0$ and of a $c>0$ such that $(\log n)^\alpha < c n^\beta$ for any $n \ge n_0$.

Comment: You can easily show that after taking logarithm of both sides, ratio of left hand to right hand side converges to zero. Since logarithm is monotonic and they both go to infinity, you can conclude the result.

Comment: I think that you need to assume $\beta \ge 0$ (and not necessarily $\alpha \ge 0$).

Comment: I think you mean $\beta \gt 0$ @Steven (mentioned and proved here https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/139476/trouble-with-big-o-notation-proof-by-definition/139481#139481). One more: I have doubt, that someone who reject Lhopital, accept derivative.

Comment: @zkutch. Nice! My answer is about the same thing but its working around the limit by taking the derivatives. I don't know if OP's professors is fine with derivatives but since we are dealing with asymptotic behaviors, it is expected for tools from calculus to appear naturally in proofs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following identities:
$$
(\ln n)^a \le n^\beta \iff \ln (\ln n)^a \le \ln n^\beta \iff
a \ln \ln n \le \beta \ln n.
$$

This is trivial if $\alpha \le 0$, so we consider the case $\alpha > 0$.

For simplicity substitute $t= \ln \ln n$ and $\gamma = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$. Notice that $\gamma \ge 0$. We obtain:
$ 
\gamma t \le  e^t \iff \gamma t - e^t \le 0  
$

To show that $\alpha t \le \beta e^t$ for sufficiently large $t$, we take the derivative of $h(t) = \gamma t - e^t$:
$$
h'(t) =\gamma - e^t.
$$

This shows that for $t \ge \ln \gamma$, $h(t)$ is monotonically non-increasing.
Moreover, for $t=\ln \gamma$ we already have $h(t) \le 0$, indeed $h(\ln \gamma) =\ln \gamma-\gamma \le 0$ since the logarithm is a monotonically increasing function.

Hence, in the definition of big-Oh with $n_0$ and $c$, we can pick $n_0 = \ln \gamma = \ln \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ and $c=1$.